# XCODE 4.6 C++ template function with function pointer as a parameter in template class

Tags: c++, xcode, templates, pointers, arguments

I have been struggling with this one for about a half day and it seem that at least XCode 4.6 has a bug where certain declaration of template class would violate the language and allow to pass const data from within class to external functions with parameters delcared as without const modifiers.

The example below WILL COMPILE, even tough template declaration of 
Tcaller::call() method specifies const arguments passed as reference 
but static cmp function is providing useless *const & modifiers.

```
template< typename T> struct Tcalled
{
    // !!!error - this prototype doesn't protect the data passed to function
    // because it should be declared with const modifiers but it wouldn't compile then.
    // SEE: Below my NOTE for correct function prototype.
        static bool cmp(const Tcalled*& item, const int& key) //<- correct but doesn't work
        static bool cmp(Tcalled* const & item, const int& key) //<- invalid but works!!
        {
            return (item->index = key); /// error - we modify const object here !
        }

    T index;
};

template < typename T> struct Tcaller
{
    Tcaller(){}

    template < typename K, bool (*compare)(const T& item, const K& key) >
    bool call(int k) const { return compare(data, k); }

    T       data;

};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const Tcaller<Tcalled<int>* > tmp;  // <- const data
    int k = 1;

    tmp.call<int,Tcalled<int>::cmp>(k);  //call here WILL modify const data !!

}
```

And the question : HOW I can force XCode to obey the rules and allow me to prototype 
my static function as it was declared for template parameter ? As for now these are the errors from XCode I get when I declare my static method correctly :

No matching member function for call to 'call'
Candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'compare'

Thanks!

Comment: `const Tcalled*` is pointer to const Tcalled, `Tcalled* const` is const pointer to Tcalled. they are different things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you mean that it works when the argument is declared as `Tcalled<T>* const & item` and the body of `cmp` should be using `==` not `=`.

You have a misunderstanding about the way template arguments are instantiated. It's not just a copy-paste substitution of the template arguments. You're expecting that `const T&` when instantiated with `T` as `Tcalled<int>*` will be equivalent to `const Tcalled<int>*&`; that is, a "reference to pointer to const `Tcalled<int>`.

However, this is wrong, the `const` applies to the whole `T` type. So really, after instantiation, `const T&` is equivalent to `Tcalled<int>* const&`. This is why having the argument declared as `Tcalled* const & item` works fine.

To get this to work with the declaration as `const Tcalled<T>*& item`, a number of things have to change:

1. The `call` function template arguments should be defined like so:

   ```
   template < int (*compare)(T& item) >
   ```

   That is, the function pointer type takes a `T&`, not a `const T&`. This makes sense as the `cmp` function does not take a reference to `const` object at all (it takes a reference to non-`const` pointer).
2. The `call` function should not be `const`:

   ```
   int call() { return compare(data); }
   ```

   This is because it's passing its member `T` to compare, which is a reference to non-`const` object (the pointer itself is not `const`). It can't do that if it is a `const` function because it cannot guarantee that `compare` won't modify the object.
3. `Tcaller` must be instantiated with `T` as `const Tcalled<int>*`:

   ```
   Tcaller<const Tcalled<int>* > tmp;
   ```

Comment: Thanks you for taking the time to answer. I figured this out  but still how it can be that compiler allows to actually MODIFY const object - see my updated code above . Shouldn't I be able to rely on compiler's messages or warnings ? Plus - still valid question then - HOW to declare similar to above with correct way of preserving 'constness' in external , static functions ?

Comment: I was affraid of this solution to be honest! I did it initially but then this forced me to have only const data within template - since this is just a dummy example it might looks like a good solution, but in real code I would stuck with const data type as template argument which is unacceptable as this is container class for non-const data .. confused :S

Comment: @seeoneself The `data` member is not `const`. It's a non-`const` pointer to a `const` object.

Comment: @seeoneself Please read [Why am I getting an error converting a `Foo**` → `Foo const**`?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/constptrptr-conversion.html). The only difference is that you're initialising a `Foo const*&` with a `Foo*`, but the reasoning is the same.

Comment: Ok, I think I confirmed that this isn't the solution I need. I did apply all the modifications and explicitly specified const Tcalled<int>* as template param, but I ended up with assignable pointer stored in Tcaller, but without the possibility to access stored data via pointers (e.g can't access data->index = 0 in call() method since they are const). Any solution for that ? What I wanted is to have a container of non-const objects but with way to declare them const when passed as references to static methods. Sorry for prolonging this but really wanna find out.

Comment: Although accepted , the answer above still is not a solution for what I needed - but it certainly is answering the question. Thank you for participation - learned today another thing - C++ still has got plenty of quirks for me :P